# Getting a date dropdown on my webpage using jquery library.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Jquery. I am designing a web application. On one of the pages, in the form fields, there is a date field which I would like the user to fill using a date drop down menu. How can I include a drop down date menu using Jquery or JS?

Comment: Check out http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Referenced from here
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Thank you very much. How critical is style.css that you have linked to in your ninth line?

Comment: close the question if your got ur answer

Comment: styles.css is not impt

Comment: Thank you folks for your contributions. I have some chunk of working code.

Answer (score 0):

check it out this one:

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

it will help you

Answer (score 0):

**Simple webform.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script>
          $(function() {
              $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                  yearRange: "-100:+20",
                  changeMonth: true,
                  changeYear: true
              });
         }); 
      </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="webform" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input id="datepicker" name="datepicker" type="Text" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

refer this link for [more information](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

It will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a Jquery datepicker, for the same. You need to add Jquery reference in your application and then use the code like this:

```
function bindPicker() {
        $("input[type=text][id*=Date]").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+1",   //Year range, 1 indicates one year ahead from current
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "../../images/Calender.png",  //path of image you want to attach
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy" //this is the format of date 
        });
    }
```

The textbox on which this will be implemented must have Date as suffix in the ID.
As the code is written like:

```
input[type=text][id*=Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options out there, but one of the most recommended options will be to use the jQuery Datepicker.

Here is a demo implementing one use case... [click here to view it](http://jsfiddle.net/8TUr6/)

The following code is pull from the jQuery Datepicker site I linked below

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true
    });
  });
```

Here are some reference sites as well

[Usage Demos](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger)

[Datepicker api](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)